# fortify Json Injection in java using GSON object

Tags: java, json

I want to deserialize json string by using Gson. I am getting a json from a web service ResponseEntity which I am converting it to String and then setting it to Model Object using gson library. On running the code on Fortify security, It is giving me Json injection error on below code with following message :

> The data is written to a JSON stream. In this case the JSON is written
>   by fromJson()

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class);
```

Any solution?

Comment: I would say there's no even slight possibility you could inject something to json using GSON library. I'm looking forward to see what's gonna be next...